# Get related custom post by specifics custom post ID

Tags: custom-post-types

I created two custom posts, one is formations and the other is Technologie.
The relation between both is  one formation have  one or  many  technologies.

After that, i have  created  a form where i select  one to three technologies.
I know that  to display the list of custom post type  is  like this :

---

```
$args = array(
        //'post__in' => array(8136),
        'post_type' => 'categories',
        'posts_per_page' => 20
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        print '<strong>' . the_title().'</strong> <br>';
        //the_excerpt();
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
```

So my question is how  to display this list only for the custom post id  '1234' ?
PS : the custom post '1234' have multiple technologie and not all !

Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't you register the "technologies" as a *custom taxonomy* instead? That way, querying related posts would be easy and faster..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it with that  but i don't think this is so optimized!

```
function list_formation(){
$args = array(,

    'post_type' => 'categories',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    
    $formations = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'formations',
        'post__in' => array(16061),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'categories', // name of custom field
                'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', 
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    ));
   
    if($formations){

        foreach ($formations as $categorie){
           // $list = get_field('formations', $formation->ID);
           // list of categorie  with ID  formation
            echo   the_title()  . '</br>';

        }

    }
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

}

Comment: I'm curious about that `post__in` - why is it added there? And note that `the_title()` echo the output, so don't do `echo the_title()` and instead, in your case, just do `the_title( '', '<br>' );` without the "echo".

Comment: Hi Sally, thanks for  all, the  post__in is to  take the list of  a specific  post i want to display the list for.